# Assign Enum Values in Java

Tags: java, enums

If I have two enums, say:

```
public enum E1 {
    A, B
}

public enum E2 {
    A, B
}
```

Is there any way I can assign a value of the enum type E2 to the value of type E1, like this:

```
E2 var = E1.B;
```

(Assuming that I know in advance that B exists in both enums)

**Edit:**

I understand that Java doesn't allow this. Maybe I should explain this as well then. I have a variable (x) of type **enum E1** (it can be A or B). For the task that I'm trying to achieve, I need to have another variable of type **enum E2** with the same value. The way that I'm handling this right now is basically:

```
if (x == E1.A) {
    E2 var = E2.A;
} else {
    E2 var = E2.B;
}
```

So I guess what I'm asking this is that is there any nicer way to do this?

Comment: A cat is a cat, a dog is a dog, it's the same for E1 and E2

Comment: That's not possible with enums in Java. You can have the enums implement interfaces, and that's it.

Comment: You're not using the right tool for the job if you're trying to do this ...

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? If you tell us what `E1`, `E2` and `A`  and `B` really are, you might get better answers.

Comment: did you find any of the answer above helpfull?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

`E1` and `E2` are two different enum types. Imagine you were developing a card game application and you had an enum for Suite and an enum for Rank. What you are asking is equivalent to trying to say that a card can have a Suite of `Rank.TEN` or a Rank of `Suite.HEARTS`. It just doesn't make sense, and isn't how enums work.

Comment: Thanks. I assume even if the two enums have the exact same staff inside them (say both E1 and E2 have 'A' and 'B'), this is still not possible, right?

Comment: @Babak Correct. A name is just a name. The compiler and the application itself knows the difference, though. `Instrument.BASS` and `Fish.BASS` are two separate entities.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this indirectly if you let both enum implement the same interface:

```
interface CommonEnumInterface{}

public enum E1 implements  CommonEnumInterface{
A, B
} 

public enum E2 implements  CommonEnumInterface{
C, D
}

CommonEnumInterface myE  = E1.A;
myE  = E2.D;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the answer as commented above, is you can't do it.

Enums in Java are type-safe and have their own namespace. It means your enum will have a type for example "Currency" and you can not assign any value other than specified in Enum Constants.  E1 is E1 and E2 is E2 namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Well - looking at your second snippet, what you could do is to define `E2` as

```
enum E2 {
    A, B
}
```

and `E1`as

```
enum E1 {

    A(E2.A), B(E2.B);

    private E2 e2;

    E1(E2 e2) {
        this.e2 = e2;
    }

    public E2 getE2() {
        return e2;
    }

}
```

like this you can simply write your `if` statement as

```
E2 var = x.getE2();
```

The idea behind this solution is, that enums like any other class in Java can have properties (`private E2 e2`), constructors (`E1(E2 es) {...}`) and methods (`public E2 getE2()`). Like that you can "add" any other values to your enum instances and use a getter to query them later on.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO, java is not allowing that

I need more info about what exactly you need to do, but  you can achieve something similar doing something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    E2 myE2 = E2.valueOf(E1.A.name());
    System.out.println(myE2);
    }

    enum E1 {
    A, B
    }

    enum E2 {
    A, B
    }
```

and note that will work ONLY because the field A is defined in both enums, otherwise is not going to work failing with an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant ...`

but this workaround is exactly what you post when you say

> *(Assuming that I know in advance that B exists in both enums)*

Answer (score 0):

Since you can define `enums` as 'lightweight classes' conforming to interfaces with their own properties and methods, you can write up your combining rules something like this:

Upholstery.java

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Upholstery {

    public List<Material> combinesWith();

}
```

Material.java

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Material {

    public List<Upholstery> combinesWith();
}
```

Upholsteries.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public enum Upholsteries implements Upholstery {
    SATIN {
        @Override
        public List<Material> combinesWith() {
            return Arrays.asList(Materials.PLASTIC);
        }
    },
    LEATHER {
        @Override
        public List<Material> combinesWith() {
            return Arrays.asList(Materials.MAHOGANY);
        }
    }
}
```

Materials.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public enum Materials implements Material {
    MAHOGANY {
        @Override
        public List<Upholstery> combinesWith() {
            return Arrays.asList(Upholsteries.SATIN,
                                 Upholsteries.LEATHER);
        }
    },
    PLASTIC {
        @Override
        public List<Upholstery> combinesWith() {
             return Arrays.asList(Upholsteries.SATIN);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you could add additional methods to the interfaces, or modify the signature of `combinesWith()` to implement more complex logic - e.g. `combinesWith(FurnitureType f, double budget)`.